# What's the point of having a virtual address that's larger than the effective address?

Tags: cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, powerpc

I'm familiar with virtual memory and the idea of virtual versus physical addresses. I'm also familiar with the multi-level page translation scheme. One thing that I newly came across though was the idea of an "effective" address. Looking into it, its used to index into a segmented address space, and you need to convert it to a virtual address in the linearized address space. On the surface this makes sense to me, but I then found a diagram like this:

---

[image]

**[Source](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E412/lectures/2009-09-18_ppc64vm.pdf)**

---

I don't really get what the point of going from a 64-bit EAddr to a 80-bit VAddr is. You can have 2^36 unique VSIDs since the ESID is 36 bits. That combined with the 2^16 different Page Index values means you only really have access to 2^52 different Virtual Page Numbers, not 2^68 like you'd expect from an 80-bit VAddr.

So why does this system bother to do any of this? Moving around 80 bits when you only use 60 sounds like a waste of wiring. Is there something I'm missing? Am I misunderstanding how segments work?

Comment: You always want more virtual address space than physical memory if you're talking about a flat memory model (which as [Linus Torvalds explained made x86 PAE a really poor design for the way Linux wanted to manage memory](https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae)).  But PPC32 uses segmentation to get more address space so that's a bit different.

Comment: 80-bit seems a bit excessive, and yeah requires more tag bits in the TLB, and possible an extra level of page tables unless there's some requirement in current HW that upper bits must be 0 or sign-extended.  But I'm not familiar with the details of PowerPC.  Maybe that's leaving room for 64-bit plus ESID to expand PPC64 past 64-bit address space?

Answer (score 4):

The "virtual address" here has a different meaning than is commonly understood in the virtual / physical sense.

It is specific to the Hash Page Table (HPT) MMU that PowerPC uses for address translation.
A single hash table structure is used globally to translate addresses.
Different memory contexts (e.g. processes) use individual segment tables so they will generate unique virtual addresses.
The virtual address is used as the key to the lookup translations in the shared hash page table.
The virtual address needs to be larger than the effective address range so that different contexts can have unique translations in the hash table.

For more details, have a look at the [POWER ISA](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=power-isa-version-3-0). In particular Book III: Chapter V Storage Control.

Comment: Ah, so you can use most of the 64-bit "effective address" space without lots of work trying to find a non-conflicting hash, I guess?  Interesting.

Comment: So the idea basically is to expand into a wider space to reduce hash conflicts? And this "virtual" address is the _only_ thing used to index the hash table which means we better  have a large enough address to handle multiple processes? Doesn't this essentially limit the number of processes that can be supported?

Comment: Yes, it is done to reduce hash conflicts and to provide memory protection amongst processes.
A hash is taken of the virtual address (VA), that is used to index into the Hash Page Table.
For each index their are 8 possible Hash Page Table Entries.
These need to be searched for (among other things) the entry that matches (part of) the VSID of the VA being translated.
This is how processes are protected from other processes accessing their memory because they should have unique VSIDs.
Things get more complicated with secondary hashes and so on.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run out of space in the Hash Page Table.
It is the Operating System's responsibility to manage this.
For example, on PowerPC, the Linux kernel still maintains the generic radix page tables.
If there is not enough space, the kernel is able to move things in and out of the Hash Page Table as needed.

Comment: @jpn the hash would also have to include the PID to make sure processes get separate VSIDs right? I read the manual and the Segment Table Entry doesn't seem to have anything to check whether that entry belongs to that process. Unless the Segment Table is unique to each process? In that case, why merge the page tables into a single page table? Is it cuz it's an inverted page table?

Comment: This is similar to exposing an address space ID. A unified (multi-"process") hierarchical page table could be architected similarly by having an n-bit ASID that indexes the top level(s) of the unified page table. Likewise a unified hashed page table could have used an ASID to avoid conflicts, but such would not have allowed finer-grained (segment) sharing but only page and address space grained. Exposure of segments may facilitate certain forms of memory sharing (vaguely similar to a single-address-space OS).

Comment: The OS is responsible setting up the segment table correctly for each process when it runs.
It can ensure the VSIDs used by processes will be unique to that process.

Comment: As for some potential benefits of the HPT: 

*  Efficient sharing of memory regions by arranging processes to share segment table entries.

*  Context switches only need the segment table to be changed.

* There are no page directories to be walked.